# Upload 6 MB image in magento

Tags: magento

I wants to upload 6MB image in the products of the magento store. Please help me where i have to change my maximum limit ? This code did not work in php.ini file 
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
Any suggestion would be appreciable

Comment: When we upload the image larger than 2mb.then javascript alert box show and it contains message look like this. Maximum allowed file size for upload is 2M. Please check your server PHP settings

Comment: Vijay - don't keep repeating the same question, edit your existing question instead. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Typically the server process (apache, httpd or php-cgi) needs to be restarted after making changes to php.ini. This might be why you are not seeing any difference.

Another way is to put your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings in a .htaccess file in the root of your Magento directory. Apache tends to read that more often.

Comment: @vijay, If this resolved the problem for you then please tick the check mark besides this answer. That will let others know what the correct answer is.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting an error when you upload the file, or does it just time out? It might be that the dimensions of the image (say 4,000 x 5,000) are too big for scaling/cropping.

Comment: When we upload the image larger than 2mb.then javascript alert box show and it contains message look like this.  Maximum allowed file size for upload is 2M.
Please check your server PHP settings.

Answer (score 1):

Place a file in your root with  in it and call it phpinfo.php. Now go to http://www.yoursite.com/phpinfo.php and see what the maximum upload size is.

If you are on shared hosting it may not be possible to increase your php settings beyond what your hosting provider allows. This could be the reason why your settings are not taking hold. Run phpinfo.php and take things from there.

Comment: You also need to give the new file this content: `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: Thanks - I did put that in there between 'with ... in it' but not using whatever code tags are needed to get that to show up. Well spotted!

Comment: Stack Overflow is interpreting the angle brackets as an HTML tag and stripping it out. Surround the code with backticks or use the `{}` button when editing.